# Is there a default writable folder on a php installation for creating files?

Tags: php

I cannot believe this hasn't been asked before, but I cannot find the answer on stackoverflow, please redirect me if this is a duplicate and I'm too retarded to find it.

I am creating a script that will download a kmz file from my custom google map, then will unzip it, read the xml and create a web page that lists all my markers. But I don't have access to the servers to create a writable folder so where can I download the kmz file to then unzip it?

Tried the temp folder (/var/tmp) and it seems to download the file, but I cannot work on the file afterwards or extract it, probably because the file gets deleted right after I call fclose, after downloading, as it doesn't exist anymore if I scan the directory.

**UPDATE:**

To answer question, the file is immediately deleted because it is a shared server and there are tons of session files in that folder that are created by all the visitors of each websites

Comment: Great idea - Every installation of PHP and you end up with a writeable folder. The hackers would love that information

Comment: @EdHeal He just means a folder that's writable by server scripts.

Comment: @barmar - I know - But that is a good target for other technologies.

Comment: have a look at sys_get_temp_dir, tempnam, tmpfile

Comment: @EdHeal If the server allows uploading, it obviously has to have a writable directory. Since this is a common feature of many applications, it has to exist.

Comment: Files in `/var/tmp` shouldn't be deleted immediately. Please post your code that's trying to use this.

Comment: @Barmar - You can just upload to a database or use a directory that has a bit more "randomness" to it. I prefer the former

Comment: @EdHeal Store zipped data in a database? I know it's possible, but why would you use a database to do a job so well suited to a filesystem?

Comment: @BenHarold - Meta data storage, easy to clean, replication.

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, store the relevant metadata in the database, not the binary data. I don't know what "easy to clean" means, but replication is most certainly an argument *against* storing binary data in a database. Replication is hard enough without the **enormous** overhead of storing a ton of binary data. You want to replicate static assets? WHY?! Put static assets on a CDN and reference their location in the database. Define an interface for the filesystem so you can swap out CDNs if necessary. Please, for the children, do not store binary data in a database. A database is for indexable data.